# Что за выражение print(2>#)

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
print(2>#)
```

что это за выражение такое? и что будет в итоге? сегодня случайно ввел и интерпретатор не выдал ошибки, а ждал от меня какой то ввод.

Comment: Думаю, `#)` воспринялось интерпрератором как закомментированная строка, поэтому реально вы ввели `print(2>`, вот интепретатор ожидает когда будет закрыта скобка

Answer (score 5):

```
print(2>#)
```

Будет запрашивать у Вас ввод строки до тех пор, пока вы не закроете скобку `)`.

Пример:

```
print(2>#)
1)
```

Результат:

```
True # 2>1
```

Answer (score 0):

Символ `#` в Питоне значит, что этот символ и всё последующее в этой строке будет считаться *комментарием* и интерпретатор Питона будет это просто *игнорировать*.

И так, когда вы написали

```
print(2>#)
```

то часть `#)` является *комментарием* и будет *игнорирована* - как бы вы просто написали

```
print(2>
```

Это не завершена команда, а вы нажали на клавишу <kbd>Enter</kbd>, потому интерпретатор Питона переходит на новую строку и будет ждать на закрывающую скобку на этой строке. Пока вы опять просто нажали на <kbd>Enter</kbd>, эта ситуация будет повторяться.